# Good places to share and showcase software on the web?

Tags: publish

Quite simply: is there a place such as DeviantArt, but purely for the purpose of sharing *software* (and source if preferred)? I'm aware that DA has plenty of software, but only related to customisations and UI hacks.

I recently came across some really useful apps I had made from way back and besides posting it on an online code hosting site or a personal portfolio that no one will ever find, is there some more *community-ish* places on the internet I've missed out on where coding mercenaries share and show off?

Comment: Like Sourceforge, github, gitorious or Google Code?

Comment: I think OP wants some exposure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally host small snippets on my website, larger projects on Google Code, and use [Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/) to link them "socially" - this is for open-source projects, of course. Perhaps Ohloh is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If your applications are fairly large-scale and useful, consider adding them to [SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net/). Otherwise, for tiny stuff, personal websites seem to be the way to go. Create a page for you applications, along with some well-documented descriptions and keywords. If your applications are indeed unique enough, that should get you plenty of exposure through Google and other search engines.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could always try [proggit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming), I often see people push out their programs on it.